# jqZoom doesn't work if images have guids as names

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jqzoom

I am using jqZoom, a jquery plugin, to render an image gallery.

[jqZoom Project Page](http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/)

The docs say to create thumbnails like this:

```
<a class="zoomThumbActive" href="javascript:void(0);" rel="{gallery: 'gal1', smallimage: './imgProd/SMALLIMAGE1.jpg',largeimage: './imgProd/LARGEIMAGE1.jpg'}">  
    <img src="imgProd/thumbs/THUMBIMG1.jpg">  
</a>
```

which works if you use "regular" names as per example. But my images have guids as names and the plug in fails:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
>   jquery.jqzoom-core.js:240 $.extend.swapimage jquery.jqzoom-core.js:240
>   (anonymous function) jquery.jqzoom-core.js:191 x.event.dispatch
>   jquery.1.10.2.min.js:5 v.handle

Using Chrome Dev Tools the failing functon is as below:

```
    swapimage: function (link) {
                    el.largeimageloading = false;
                    el.largeimageloaded = false;
                    var options = new Object();

                    //alert(eval("(" + $.trim($(link).attr('rel')) + ")"));

                    console.log($.trim($(link).attr('rel')));
 options = $.extend({}, eval("(" + $.trim($(link).attr('rel')) + ")"));
                    alert($.trim($(link).attr('rel')));

                    if (options.smallimage && options.largeimage) {
                        var smallimage = options.smallimage;
                        var largeimage = options.largeimage;
                        $(link).addClass('zoomThumbActive');
                        $(el).attr('href', largeimage);
                        img.attr('src', smallimage);
                        lens.hide();
                        stage.hide();
                        obj.load();
                    } else {
                        alert('ERROR :: Missing parameter for largeimage or smallimage.');
                        throw 'ERROR :: Missing parameter for largeimage or smallimage.';
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

and it fails on this line in particular:

```
 options = $.extend({}, eval("(" + $.trim($(link).attr('rel')) + ")"));
```

Looking around the web it seems such errors are the result of the eval creating invalid javascript objects and so apparently we have to reformat the output as a Json string so it correctly interpreted as parameters

But I cant seem to "force" it to interpret this as proper jSON. If I replace the line above with

```
options = $.extend({}, JSON.parse($.trim($(link).attr('rel'))))
```

I get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token g
>   ef01e51a-d5c5-49ea-bd21-9c4e7f9acbb6:1 {gallery: 'gal1', smallimage:
>   '\xc_small\58f54dc5-b412-4ffd-af51-5bc6863b280d.jpg',largeimage:
>   '\xc_full\58f54dc5-b412-4ffd-af51-5bc6863b280d.jpg'}

So how do I do this?

Comment: _Sticking on the older version just to get out of writing slightly more unambiguous code is all-around terrible advice_ - it was a sugggestion,  not an advice, along with the JSON enforcing (which works with single quotes also BTW)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your backslashes are being interpreted as escape characters. Use forward slashes. For example, the `rel` attribute could read:

```
rel='{"gallery": "gal1", "smallimage": "/xc_small/58f54dc5-b412-4ffd-af51-5bc6863b280d.jpg", "largeimage": "/xc_full/58f54dc5-b412-4ffd-af51-5bc6863b280d.jpg"}'
```

Note that I've double-quoted the keys and the string values in the JSON and used single quotes for the `rel` attribute. Strings must be double-quoted in JSON, and keys are strings.

Comment: "Note that I've double-quoted the keys and the string values in the JSON and used single quotes for the rel attribute" - that's thelikely the actual problem that causes "unexpected token `g`". As in, the `g` in `gallery`.

Comment: Right you are millimoose

Comment: WGAF. It doesnt matter, downvoting for this is extreme. Sorry I wasted my time.

Comment: Absolutely. Bloody. Marvellous. Thanks.